# How to switch between different types of R in unit testing

Tags: r, unit-testing, version

I want to create unit testing for different versions of R e.g. 3.6.3, 4.0 etc. I know that I can install older versions of R and try unit testing for each of them, but is there any possibility how can I do it in easier way ? For example artificially provide other R versions and loop them ?

Comment: Follow the example of the data.table devs: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/tree/master/.ci